# Regex replace only inside a pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace all dashes that are inside square brackets but leave the ones that aren't.

String: `dont-change-this[only-change-inside-brackets]`

Result: `dont-change-this[only_change_inside_brackets]`

The way I'm currently doing it is by capturing everything in the square brackets and then replacing.

```
regex = /(\[([a-z-]+)\])/
testString = "dont-change-this[only-change-inside-brackets]"

testString.match regex
testString.sub(regex, $1.gsub(/-/, '_'))
```

It works, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this in just one expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sub (or gsub) with a block:

```
my_string.sub(/\[.*?\]/){|x|x.tr('-','_')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a suggestion and i dont think its an ideal way, but you can actually split the sentence and then match the second element of the array returned.

```
2.0.0p247 :079 > str = "dont-change-this[only-change-inside-brackets]"
=> "dont-change-this[only-change-inside-brackets]"
2.0.0p247 :080 > s = str.split("[")
=> ["dont-change-this", "only-change-inside-brackets]"] 
2.0.0p247 :081 > s[1].gsub(/-/, '_')
=> "only_change_inside_brackets]"
```